# What is Error Occurred during Linearization

Tags: pdftron

I am using pdftron for merging and splitting of pdf documents. When i am trying to save the pdf document it gives an error . `**Message Error occurred during linearization. The specified path is invalid.**`.

Error is very rare and it is also not recreateable. Screen shot attached.

[pdftron error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te8Kz.png)

I want to know why this error occurrs, and what does it mean?

Comment: Version 6.8.7 is from sometime in 2018. When did this issue start occurring? What changed at that time? This happens with every PDF? Or a specific PDF file?

Comment: Hi @Ryan it is happening for specific PDF , there are multiple save options one them is e_linearized

Comment: If the issue is file specific then that PDF would have to be sent to PDFTron support. Though first step would be try latest PDFTron SDK.